# What's the difference between 'json" gem and 'json_pure' gem?

Tags: ruby, json, rubygems

I need a library to handle JSON objects in Ruby. There are two gems available `json` and `json_pure` on http://rubygems.org/search?query=json

`json_pure` is written only in Ruby while `json` is using C. All I understand is that `json` is faster because of the usage of C. So is `json` better for production?

Both seem to be easily installed just by running `gem install` command. When I install Nokogiri, I need to do something extra. I thought the extra work is required because Nokogiri is using C extensions, but I don't need to do anything extra for `json` gem.

- What's advantages and disadvantages for `json` and `json_pure`?
- Assuming installing `json` is easy, what's the benefit of `json_pure`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nokogiri needs extra libraries because it uses libXML. `json` has no library dependencies, so you don't need anything extra.

The advantage of `json` is what you said: It is in C, so performance is better than `json_pure`.

The advantage of `json_pure` can be if you don't have [MRI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_MRI). For example, the `json_pure` gem can be installed in JRuby/Maglev or other implementations. The `json` gem can't be; it needs an [FFI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libffi) plugin to do that.

Comment: The json gem should now work with JRuby. It is currently listed (alongside json_pure) as a substitute for the faster yajl-ruby gem via https://github.com/jruby/jruby/wiki/C-Extension-Alternatives.